# Llamar a clase ubicada en otro archivo

Tags: php

Cómo podría llamar a mis funciones dentro de una clase que estén ubicadas en otro archivo sin recurrir a `include`

Por ejemplo tengo el archivo **test.php** que contiene:

```
<?php
    echo Customer::test();
?>
```

Y el archivo con la clase `customer` es **Customer.class.php** y contiene:

```
<?php
    class Customer {
        public function test(){
            echo "test";
        }
    }
?>
```

Hay algún método o archivo de configuración donde pueda definir por ejemplo, que cuando llame a una clase, esta busque en una carpeta llamada clases por ejemplo?

Comment: Mediante PS-4 que es la recomendación para auto carga de clases en PHP, llevas algo al momento?

Comment: No se cómo funciona PS-4

Comment: Los autoloaders también usan `include` o `require`. Incluso usando PSR-4 tienes que cargar los ficheros de alguna forma. Mira [estos ejemplos](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por medio de PSR-4 el cual es una *especificación*<sup>1</sup> para la auto carga de clases

**Nota importante**

> Para este caso tuve que bajar de PHP 7.4 a PHP 7.3.13 por un posible *bug*, recomiendo leas los enlaces provistos al final

- Requieres tener *composer* instalado

Dentro de tu proyecto de PHP a nivel de la raíz ejecutas el siguiente comando:

```
composer init
```

Con este comando se te va a generar un archivo llamado `composer.json` el cual deberás llenar con los datos solicitados.

- Configurando el `composer.json`

Deberás tener una estructura similar a la siguiente en especial revisa lo que esta después de la clave `require`

```
{
    "name": "tuautor",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "yomero",
            "email": "yomero@mail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "clases/"
        }
    }
}
```

**Explicación**

- `App` es el namespace principal que englobará tu desarrollo y que identificará las clases que estén contenidas en tu carpeta `clases`; entonces todo archivo que exista dentro de `clases` deberá estar precedido por dicho valor así:

  Class1.php

  namespace App;

  Class2.php

  namespace App
- `clases` es la ruta física es decir la carpeta que tendrá contenidas todas tus clases a usar.

Dentro de tu carpeta clases genera el archivo llamado `Customer.php` que deberá lucir mas o menos así:

```php
<?php
    namespace App;

    class Customer
    {
        public function test()
        {
            echo "test";
        }
    }
```

- Le antepusimos dicho namespace para indicar que existe bajo este *contexto* y que sin la invocación de este no podrá ser accedido

Ahora debemos generar la carpeta **vendor** con el siguiente comando:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

El comando anterior se va a encargar de registrar nuestro namespace `App` que apunta a nuestra carpeta `clases` dentro de un array como el siguiente:

```php
<?php

    // autoload_psr4.php @generated by Composer

    $vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
    $baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

    return array(
        'App\\' => array($baseDir . '/clases'),
    );
```

Una vez hecho lo anterior en la raíz de tu proyecto crea tu archivo llamado *test.php* y dentro del mismo escribe lo siguiente:

```php
<?php

    require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
    use App\Customer;

    $objeto = new Customer;
    echo $objeto->test();
```

- Invocamos a la clase `Customer` por medio de su namespace completo que es `App\Customer` recordando que `App` es el espacio de nombre vinculado a la carpeta `clases` de donde queremos extraer a `Customer.php`.
- La funcionalidad la otorga la línea que hace el `require` a `autoload.php` donde si bien aún debes requerirlo, solo será un archivo que a su vez administra por *debajo* todos los archivos de la carpeta `clases`
- El resto es una instancia normal común y corriente

**Referencias**

- [psr4-spec](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)
- [posible bug de composer en PHP 7.4](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/8457)
- [namespaces en PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.php)

Comment: Sería buena idea explicar también que es PSR-4, ya que el OP tampoco sabe. :P