# Invocar clases en PHP por medio de su namespace

Tags: php, php7

Estoy intentando usar namespaces en PHP si el uso de include, solamente usando use, pero siempre me dice class not found, aqui les muestro el codigo.

este primero es usado include en la clase principal:

```
namespace Prueba1;

class prueba {

    public function hi(){
        echo "Hola desde prueba1";
    }
}
```

esto estara guardado en un archivo llamado Language.php, este archivo estara guardado en una carpeta llamada Prueba, ahora en el index para usar este namespace seria asi:

```
 include ('Prueba\Language.php');
 use Language\Prueba1\prueba;

 prueba::hi();
```

este modo funciona, pero he visto por internet en donde solamente utilizan el use, ya que el include no es necesario, el use ya de por si te busca la ruta, con el use solamente seria:

```
 use Prueba\Prueba1\prueba;     //no funciona
 prueba::hi()

 use Prueba\Language\Prueba1\prueba;
 prueba::hi()   //tampoco funciona
```

como seria solamente usando el use? sin necesidad de usar el include

ACTUALIZADO:

aqui la ruta de las carpetas, dentro de la carpeta Prueba estan las clases con sus namespace:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

clase prueba:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y aqui el index para hacer uso de ellas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de error me sale que la clase prueba no se encuentra

Answer (score 1):

Los namespaces en PHP, nos van a ayudar a:

- Identificar el contexto dentro del cual existe nuestra clase
- Organizar de forma mas orgánica nuestras clases
- Poder invocar dichas clases de forma organizada por la ruta de *namespaces* a los cuales pertenecen
- Evitar colisiones de nombres al limitar donde existen
- entre muchas otras cosas mas.

Por otro lado, si revisamos tu código, tu invocas a una clase `prueba` la cual si revisamos tu árbol de carpetas se encuentra en: **`Prueba/prueba.php`** pero tu al momento de quererla usar indicas que existe **`use Language`** lo cual no veo o no identifico.

De forma muy simple y básica, tu clase `prueba` debería quedar así:

```
namespace Prueba1;

class prueba {

    public static function hi(){
        return "Hola desde prueba1";
    }
}
```

Entonces en el archivo `index` cuando quieras ocupar dicha clase lo harás de esta forma:

```
<?php

require 'Prueba/prueba.php';

use Prueba1\prueba as probando;
```

Entonces cuando invoques a la clase podrás hacer esto:

```
echo probando::hi();
```

**Observaciones**

- Te faltó indicar que el método `hi()` sea estático para poder invocarlo sin crear una instancia de la clase
- Esta forma que presento es muy rudimentaria, deberías checar sobre: [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)
- Una herramienta que nos simplifica mucho la autocarga de clases es: [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md)
- Te dejo una respuesta que te puede guiar con un ejemplo muy básico de como usar composer para la [autocarga de clases](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/318733/llamar-a-clase-ubicada-en-otro-archivo/318743#318743)

Comment: si amigo, pero he visto en paginas donde solamente usan el use, ya te dejo el link

Comment: @plus entonces están haciendo autocarga de clases, revisa sobre psr4

Comment: Solo usan el use? O también usan un composer.json y un autoloader para definir la carga de clases y luego las referencian con namespace?

Comment: https://anexsoft.com/que-son-y-ejemplo-de-namespaces-en-php

Comment: la verdad no se que estaran usando, porque soy nuevo en esto del namespace y en general

Comment: Pues revisando el ejemplo que pones me parece que se soluciona con los puntos mencionados, te invito a que revises ese link de nuevo @plus

Comment: es que el crea el archivo en dentro de una carpeta que a la vez esta dentro de otra carpeta anexsoft/helpers/hello.php, luego el namespace del archivo hello se llama anexsoft\helpers, y al llamarlo en otro archivo solo usa use anexsoft\helpers\hello, en mi caso yo tengo el archivo lenguage en la carpeta Prueba y el namespace con nombre Prueba1, al llamarlo seria use Prueba\Language y abajo llamaria prueba::hi

Comment: pero no funciona :(

Comment: dame oportunidad tener mas tiempo y edito mi respuesta

Comment: Por cierto @plus edita y agrega el árbol de carpetas que tienes y que archivos estan dentro de cada una, pero en tu ejercicio

Comment: @BetaM listo amigo

Comment: Esta hecho, espero te sirva @plus